# How to make composer NOT create a .git directory for a package

Tags: git, composer-php

I found a couple related posts, but those don't really answer my question.
Let's say I want to install this package:
https://github.com/pear/Net_Socket

an excerpt from my composer.json:

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/pear/Net_Socket.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pear/net_socket": "*",
    }
}
```

So I need it **to be installed without the .git directory** so it is not seen as a submodule in my project.
How do I make it download a "dist" version, like others said? Do I have to tag a commit?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a package is seen as a git submodule, you haven't excluded the `vendor` folder from being committed to your own repository. It is recommended to add the vendor folder to `.gitignore`, and not commit these files, only commit `composer.lock` (and `composer.json` of course).

Apart from that, running `composer install --prefer-dist` should do the job. Note that Composer seems to not change the download method used first if you change your mind later. If Composer detects a cloned repo, it is faster to just update that instead of downloading a ZIP and unpacking it. If you want to change that, delete the whole `vendor` folder and run `composer update --prefer-dist`.

Comment: But what If I like to keep my vendor folder as submodule? I made it as submodule so I can see all changes which updates are making, to identify new bugs coming from updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Using --prefer-dist is the only native solution, but there will be situations where there is simply no packaged version available, and in those cases Composer will still fall back to git clones.

The only workaround I know of is to run a cleanup script after composer install that removes Git directories. Maybe a command like this:

```
find . -type d | grep .git | xargs rm -rf
```

Be careful to run this in your vendor directory, **not your root directory**.

Comment: A little simpler, and also safer by specifying the "vendor" directory: `find vendor -type d -name \.git -exec rm -rf \{\} \;`

Comment: **DON'T USE THE COMMAND FROM THE ANSWER.** The `find grep xargs rm` command is completely unsafe. First, it will delete "xgit", "bak.git", ".github", etc. directories (because it uses `grep .git` instead of something like `grep '\/\.git$'`). Second, it will not work correctly with a space containing directories and will delete "my" and "configs" directories when "my .git configs" directory is exist (because it uses `xargs` instead of `-exec`). Look at my answer below for a safe command.

Answer (score 2):

`composer update --prefer-dist` works fine, but it might be simpler to just change the default download method for composer packages (composer.json):

```
{
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    }
  }
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install

Answer (score 1):

To safely delete only ".git" directories inside "vendor" directory, use:

```
find vendor -type d -name '.git' -exec rm -rf \{\} \+
```

Answer (score 0):

May this works well even through the Q has been put up so far a long time.
It's in composer.json

```
"scripts": {       
    "post-update-cmd": ["echo [WARNING] Delete all .git dirs", "rm -rf vendor/**/**/.git"],
    "post-install-cmd": ["echo [WARNING] Delete all .git dirs", "rm -rf vendor/**/**/.git"]
},
```