# composer generates a .git directory with my package from GitLab

Tags: php, gitlab, composer-php

I have a local GitLab running.

I configure in a `composer.json` that install a package or bundle from my gitlab, I made that part, it was complicate but i did it.

The problem that I have is that my module when is downloaded by composer, composer clones it instead downloading it so a `.git/` folder is created and I don't want that.

- It is a fresh install
- I only have the composer.json file
- I run this command to install it: `composer install -o --prefer-dist`
- I already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981292/how-to-make-composer-not-create-a-git-directory-for-a-package) post
- I test changing the repository type to vcs|git|package

My `composer.json`

```json
{
 "config":{
   "preferred-install": "dist",
   "secure-http": false
    },
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
 "repositories": [ {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "http://gitlab.local/GROUPNAME/REPOSITORY.git"
   }],
 "require": {
   "GROUPNAME/REPOSITORY": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

I tried create a tag with a specific version and add in the composer.json that version and nothing all seems equal

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you fix the issue?

Comment: No, I'm not. I couldn't resolve this problem.

Comment: @Andrew and Emiliano, help is late in coming, but check the dupe to see how to avoid this issue. :)

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a solution, I think that delete manually .git directories as workaround

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Composer doesn't know about how to download a packaged ZIP file from your local Gitlab instance. I'm not even sure Gitlab has an API for this (but I haven't looked).

Downloading a ZIP is depending on either one of these two situations:

1. The composer.json metadata points to a download location for the tagged version.
2. The repository is hosted at a well-known service with an API that allows to download ZIPs without explicitly pointing to it in the metadata (like using github.com or bitbucket.org as part of the repository URL).

In all other cases Composer can only clone the repository because that is the only information it has how to obtain the needed code version.

There's an additional methods to create downloads yourself, and it is far superior compared to listing all your private repositories that might get used inside the "repositories" key of the root `composer.json`:

Use either Satis, a local Packagist, Toran Proxy or "Private Packagist" (at https://packagist.com/), depending on your situation.

Going with Satis probably is the easiest way because it has very few requirements regarding infrastructure, it basically creates static files for a HTTP webserver.

I'd add that after reading some Composer code, I'd suspect that by setting [`gitlab-domains`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#gitlab-domains) in the (global) configuration and by using `gitlab` instead of `vcs` or `git` as the repository type, you should be able to make Composer access the Gitlab API in order to download a ZIP instead of cloning the repo (note that Composer will not switch a repo once cloned, you have to delete the `vendor` folder, then install/update one more time).

Comment: could you do an example?