# Composer: Nothing to install or update. Use my own library in my project

Tags: composer-php

My project will use my own library (username/lib) which I don't publish at packagist. Actually I want the library to be a private library. But failed. So I convert the **library** to be public accessible. Still not working.

My **project**'s composer.json content:

```
 {
        "repositories": [

            {
                "type": "vcs",
                "url": "git@github.com:username/lib.git"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is my terminal output:

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

The content of `username/lib` composer.json

```
{
    "name": "username/lib",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" : {
            "username\\lib\\" : "src"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Note: username & lib are not the real names.

Comment: have you tried `composer require username/lib:dev-master`?

Comment: Thanks mate! Please change to Answer rather than a Comment, because I want to accept your answer. I have additional question. When my lib was downloaded into my project, the .git folder also get downloaded. I haven't seen this behaviour with most of other libraries. How do I prevent my library's .git folder from being downloaded?

Comment: done, regarding the .git folder this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981292/how-to-make-composer-not-create-a-git-directory-for-a-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your composer.json is not requiring your library:

you can do so on the command line by `composer require username/lib:dev-master`